# How to reset achievements in Google Play Games?

Tags: java, android, reset, google-play-games, achievements

I made changes to the amount of XP which is gained by an achievement. Now I want to reset the achievements for users, so that their XP will be reset. It is currently too much. New achievements will reward the new XP, but the old XP is still visible in Google Play Games.

I tried to follow this guide for my developer account, and it didn't work:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/achievements/resetAll

It resulted in `{` instead of the result listed on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stealing my already earned achievements sounds like one of the fastest ways to make me uninstall your app...

Comment: Well, at least I would like to remove them on my own account. There might be one or two other users who might have received an achievement or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature seems to be available only for draft achievements.

See: https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/achievements

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests, I realized a possible issue. First of all, there is a reset button on every achievement inside the developer console. You can just reset an achievement by pressing this button. But the following requirements must be fulfilled:

1. it has to be a release signed apk which is installed for testing.
2. The app must be in alpha or beta test phase, using the same version of app that you have installed for testing (not rellay sure about that)
3. The Play Games settings for your app shouldn´t be published. You can only reset achievements for test users with an unpublished game. With game I mean the play games settings, not the app itself.

After pressing the reset, it needs long time to reset, in my test it needed about 1 hour, but maybe could be longer or shorter.

But there is a little issue, I think it´s on Googles site and I reported it to Google. The reset doesn´t work on incremental achievements.

Comment: I'm also unable to reset incremental achievements. They are no longer unlocked, but the progress remains unchanged. This means I can have an achievement at 100% that is still locked.

I've just sent a help request to Google, if I receive an update I'll add another comment.

Comment: @chris: Yes, I did it too. It´s over 4 weeks now without a result. Google cared about and asked me some questions, but until today, I heard nothing about it.

Comment: I got a reply last night: "I’ve documented your issue and escalated it to our technical team for further investigation. Our team is working to resolve this issue for you as soon as possible."

Hopefully one of us will hear more soon. I linked this SO question in my initial email to them as well.

Comment: Great, the more developers complain, the better the chances that it will be fixed.

Comment: I stumbled upon a fix today while solving a problem with cloud save. With regard to forcing an update of an app's cloud save setting, Google's documentation says "To clear the cached data on Android, open Settings > Apps > Google Play services, click on Manage Space, then click on Clear All Data." Doing this also fixed up my incremental achievements. It does mean you have to sign back into games etc., so try at your own risk :)

Comment: Hi Chris, You should post it as possible answer. Yes this could fix the problem...but It would be better to do it inside the console because it will maybe other apps data too (not sure about this)...

Comment: I totally agree, that's why I didn't want to post it as an answer. I honestly don't know what the full ramifications of clearing that data are. I don't think it would cause any permanent damage, but I can't be certain.

Comment: I got a reply this morning. There should be some changes made that take effect on Thursday, August 10 that resolve this issue. I'm not sure what time zone the reply was referring to (I'm in Sydney), so I'm going to do a test in a few days and see how it goes.

Comment: It's fixed for me now. It took a couple of minutes for the reset to come through to my device (I assume there's some caching that takes a little while to be cleared). Hopefully you get the same result!

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with resetting and modifying draft achievements, no matter what changes I made to the Google Play Console the achievements on the Android client were never updated. Incremental achievements did not reset, adding achievements did not show up in client, etc.

However, I eventually discovered that running

`startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);`

to display all achievement progress does seem to refresh the client properly. So now it works to reset and update achievements, as long as I start the achievements intent in the application afterwards.

Just adding this comment in case someone else runs into the same problem as me.

Edit: it seems like I also need to run increment on one or more achievements before it gets refreshed. In either case it is still an improvement, as it was not working at all before.